# os not importing into python class method

Tags: python, class

I am having some problems importing os into a class method that I want to use

main.py:

```
import os
import datadir
import dataops
d1 = datadir.datadir(dirtoscan)
uniques = d1.FindPrefixes(dirtoscan)
Materials = d1.SortPhotodiodeData(uniques)
dat1 = dataops.dataops(Materials)
rawdata = dat1.BigDictToArray(Materials)
```

dataops.py:

```
import os
class dataops:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def BigDictToArray(self,Materials):
        self.tardir = os.getcwd()
```

Here's the error when I try to run this on Windows 7 (I'm a newb, sorry)

```
C:\Python27\dataops.pyc in BigDictToArray(self, Materials)
     43             rawdata.append({name[0]:matdata})
     44         return rawdata
---> 45 
     46     def BigDictToArray(self,Materials):
     47         self.tardir = os.getcwd()

 NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
```

Why can't I seem to import the os module into dataops? os is called in the class datadir without a problem. The dataops and datadir are both stored in C:\Python27 if that makes any difference.

Comment: The code for `BigDictToArray()` method shown in the error listing is different that what you say is in the `dataop.py` module. Also what's in module `datadir.py` which you also `import`? Also seems strange that the `dataop.py` module has the definition of class `datadir` in it...

Comment: Code and error message are inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry about the error while I was manually copying my code. BigDictToArray is in dataops. Datadir is a module that sorts through a directory and bins data according to which sample it corresponds to. Thank you for your comments and reply!

Comment: Even with your edit, in `dataops.py` the last line says `tardir = os.getcwd()` but in the supposed error listing is says `self.tardir = os.getcwd()`. Please just copy the actual traceback and paste it into your answer (indented four spaces). The error you're getting makes no sense, so it's especially important for us to see the actual code and traceback with error message in order to help you.

Comment: Your're right, sorry about that and thanks for your patience, just finished copying, both should read self.tardir.

Comment: Normally tracebacks don't reference `.pyc` files. Try deleting the `C:\Python27\dataops.pyc` file. It's possible -- though unlikely -- that it's overriding the contents of your latest `dataops.py` module. You can also try adding an `import os` as the first line after `def BigDictToArray(self,Materials):`. That shouldn't be necessary, but it might workaround the very strange problem you're having.

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you martineau! I deleted dataops.pyc and that solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear. I suggest that you put your personal modules in another folder rather than in `C:\Python27`. In other words there shouldn't have been a `dataops.pyc` in the `C:\Python27` folder. The Python Windows installer should have added `C:\Python27` to your `PATH`, so you ought to be able execute the interpreter from other locations on your system without specifying the full path to the `python.exe` executable.